# Tricentis Tosca - Add TestStep Module doesn't include module's controls?

Tags: module, controls, tosca

I'm pretty new to Tricentis Tosca and I'm working through the Automation Specialist Level 1 training videos, but I ran into a difference between the videos and my local version of Tosca Commander.

In the videos, I see that when a Module is added to a test step (either via drag-and-drop or ctrl-T "Add TestStep" function), the Module and **all** of it's contained controls are then added to the test step. In my local Tosca app, if I add a module, for some reason, only the module name gets added and **none** of its contained controls are added. (I then have to find each Module, find all of it's controls, select them, and drag them individually under the local Module).

What am I missing here? Is there a configuration setting I'm missing or am I selecting the module incorrectly so that it's child controls are not included? Are the controls not being copied because the Module has attachments (a screenshot)?

I'm sure this is a rookie mistake, so I appreciate any advice here. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have activated the option "Hide DoNothing", which hides all entries that don't have a value. As you just added your TestStep, no entry has a value and nothing is shown.

You can deactivate that option by disabling it in the ribbon menu or by hitting the keyboard shortcut <kbd>F9</kbd>

[image]